# Skip an iteration in a rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops

I have a loop inside an .erb file like

```
<% @columns.each do |column| %>
    <td><%= column.name %></td>
<% end %>
```

Is there some simple way to skip an iteration based on the value of the column name? I tried calling "next" inside the block but it does not work because the <%= tag is expecting something to output.

Comment: The accepted answer is fine, but another useful strategy I found later is to filter the list before iterating it.

Comment: ...and traverse it one more time allocating another collection to store the results? Well... depends. The accepted answer is similar to `.lazy.filter` that does filtering as part of the same traversal without extra storage.

Comment: Yes, I am iterating over a very small collection so I did not actually care about performance, but you are right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try something like:

```
<% @columns.each do |column| %>
  <% next if condition? %>
  <td><%= column.name %></td>
<% end %>
```